# Angular2 An unhandled win32 exception ocurred in iexplorer.exe [xxxxx]

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, inspect

I have an angular2 application that runs perfectly on google chrome, but for some reason it crashes on internet explorer 11.

When opening the console with F12 key, it opens the console, but immediately after it opens a window with the message "Internet Explorer has stopped working" and provides the option to close the window or to debug.

If I click debug it shows the message "An unhandled win32 exception ocurred in iexplorer.exe [xxxxx]".

I also tried to do the same without the IE add ons, but the errors continues.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was relate to opening developer tools (F12) when two or more stylesheets are loaded in Internet Explorer 11.

For more information just go to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7115476/ .

The solution was changing to Microsoft Edge.